# Selection sort implementation in a bigger project

Tags: java, sorting, selection

I need to do a project that generates up to 100 random numbers, shows them, then you select one of few types of sorts (selection, bubble, insertion, shell..), and it sorts them. I've already done the generating part, but I'm having issues with first sort - selection sort. It displays only zeros instead of my generated and sorted numbers.

```
package projekt;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Projekt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] tablica;
        Scanner odczyt = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Give number of elements (max 100): ");
        int liczbaElementow = odczyt.nextInt();
        tablica = new int[liczbaElementow];

        if (liczbaElementow <= 100 && liczbaElementow > 0){
            System.out.println("Generated:");
            Random Generator = new Random();
            for (int idx = 1; idx <= liczbaElementow; ++idx){
                int randomInt = Generator.nextInt(101);
                System.out.print(" " +randomInt);
            }

            {
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.print("Choose sorting method (1, 2 lub 3):");
            }
            Scanner odczyt2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int ktoresort = odczyt2.nextInt();

            switch (ktoresort) {
                case 1: System.out.println("SORT 1");
                {
                    {
                        int min = 0;

                        for(int i = 0;i<liczbaElementow;i++)
                        {
                            min = i;
                            for(int j = i + 1;j<liczbaElementow;j++)
                            {
                                if(tablica[j] < tablica[min]) { min = j;}
                            }
                            int temp = tablica[i];
                            tablica[i] = tablica[min];
                            tablica[min] = temp;
                            System.out.println(tablica[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
                case 2: System.out.println("SORT 2");
                break;
                case 3: System.out.println("SORT 3");
                break;
                default:  System.out.println("incorrect value");  
                break;
            }   

            odczyt2.close();    
        }
        else if (liczbaElementow==0) {
            System.out.println("entered 0");        
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("value is biger than 100");  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you fill the array ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to remove extra lines and fix indenting. As an aside (not related to your problem, but since you mentioned you're not a programmer) you have some unnecessary brackets which are made more apparent by that, I'd suggest setting your IDE up to auto-indent if possible. Also, no need for the argument in `System.out.println(" ")`, `System.out.println()` will just print a new line. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I started writing this in classic windows notepad, then my friend told me about eclipse so there could be little mess from that beggining. 
I never really tried to type just () to create new line but i just replaced this in my code now and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you never added the generated values to the tablica here have the solution my friend

```
public class Projekt {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[] tablica;
    Scanner odczyt = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Give number of elements (max 100): ");
    int liczbaElementow = odczyt.nextInt();
    tablica = new int[liczbaElementow];


    if (liczbaElementow <= 100 && liczbaElementow > 0){

        System.out.println("Generated:");
        Random Generator = new Random();
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= liczbaElementow; ++idx){
            int randomInt = Generator.nextInt(101);
            System.out.print(" " +randomInt);
            tablica[idx-1]=randomInt;


        }

        {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.print("Choose sorting method (1, 2 lub 3):");
        }
        Scanner odczyt2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ktoresort = odczyt2.nextInt();

        switch (ktoresort) {
            case 1: System.out.println("SORT 1");
                bubbleSort(tablica);
            break;
            case 2: System.out.println("SORT 2");
                insertionSort(tablica);
            case 3: System.out.println("SORT 3");
                shelSort(tablica);
                break;
            default:  System.out.println("incorrect value");
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tablica));
        odczyt2.close();
    }
    else if (liczbaElementow==0) {
        System.out.println("entered 0");
    }

    else{
        System.out.println("value is biger than 100");
    }
}


public static void bubbleSort( int [ ] num )
{
    int j;
    boolean flag = true;   // set flag to true to begin first pass
    int temp;   //holding variable

    while ( flag )
    {
        flag= false;    //set flag to false awaiting a possible swap
        for( j=0;  j < num.length -1;  j++ )
        {
            if ( num[ j ] < num[j+1] )   // change to > for ascending sort
            {
                temp = num[ j ];                //swap elements
                num[ j ] = num[ j+1 ];
                num[ j+1 ] = temp;
                flag = true;              //shows a swap occurred
            }
        }
    }
}


public static void insertionSort( int [ ] num)
{
    int j;                     // the number of items sorted so far
    int key;                // the item to be inserted
    int i;

    for (j = 1; j < num.length; j++)    // Start with 1 (not 0)
    {
        key = num[ j ];
        for(i = j - 1; (i >= 0) && (num[ i ] < key); i--)   // Smaller values are moving up
        {
            num[ i+1 ] = num[ i ];
        }
        num[ i+1 ] = key;    // Put the key in its proper location
    }
}


public static void shelSort(int[] array) {
    int inner, outer;
    int temp;

    int h = 1;
    while (h <= array.length / 3) {
        h = h * 3 + 1;
    }
    while (h > 0) {
        for (outer = h; outer < array.length; outer++) {
            temp = array[outer];
            inner = outer;

            while (inner > h - 1 && array[inner - h] >= temp) {
                array[inner] = array[inner - h];
                inner -= h;
            }
            array[inner] = temp;
        }
        h = (h - 1) / 3;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why i didn't add values to tablica but this makes sense now. I will try to add selection sort one more time now and i'll come back if i have problems again :)

Comment: if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Comment: Just wanted to leave this open for a while before i complete writing (if i had additional questions). I added selection sort and everything is working so im accepting now

Comment: I'd like to ask if You have maybe QuickSort also? I'm trying to connect it to my generated numbers (tablica) but i have a lot of errors.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html